# How to repair possible origin problem in png files?

Tags: image-processing, image

i tell you, my daughter uses a figure cutting program called Silhouette Studio and loads and traces png files so that later a machine cuts them, recently she acquired some png files that behave in a special way, they take a long time to load,  would like to know if Mathematica has some way to check the header of these files and fix any errors that originate.
I put an image of how the file looks when I send it to cut (it comes out with white lines and they are also printed like that), I don't know if the file is wrong or something else happens, any other png works good.
I attach a copy of the file so you can see it.
Any help is welcome
[image]

[original](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9pv8m9iy30otrt1/clipart-07.png?dl=0)

Comment: I would say resolution of the image 6250x6250 is unnecessary too big which can cause problems because of using too much memory. So resize the image to, say, 800x800, save it and then try using it. On the other hand what the question has to do with Mathematica is not clear to me.

Comment: I have seen that MMA has enormous power to process images, as these PNGs behave a bit differently than others I thought they might be damaged and use image processing to repair any abnormalities